# how to determine how many and what kind of arguments are passed to hooks

Tags: hooks, filters, actions

I am not able to understand a very logic behind add_action / add_filter

Consider following example:

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
  if ($query->is_search) {
     $query->set('post_type', 'page');
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

My questions are

- How can I know wheter function 'SearchFilter' accepts any argument or
  not?
- What will be that argument / what will be it's type?
- How can I determine for which action/filter there is any argument?
- Should every action / filter return the passed parameter?

Answer (score 3):

When calling an action hook using

```
add_action('some_action_tag','callback_function',$priority,$number_of_arguments);
```

The callback function is called when a `do_action()` call is fired with the corresponding tag for example:

```
do_action('some_action_tag',$argument1,$argument2,$argument3....);
```

And when calling a filter hook using:

```
add_filter('some_filter_tag','callback_function',$priority,$number_of_arguments);
```

The callback function is called when a `apply_filters()` call is fired with the corresponding tag for example:

```
$value = apply_filters('some_filter_tag',$argument1,$argument2,$argument3...);
```

Now as you can see the main difference is that the action hook basically lets you run your own function at a given point,, and a filter hook lets you filter (change/alter/clean ...) the value of a specific variable.

So an action "hooked" callback_function accepts arguments only if any were specified and a filter "hooked" callback_function accepts at least one argument which is the value to alter itself and more arguments only if specified.

As for you questions

> How can I know whether function 'SearchFilter' accepts any argument or
>   not?

The hooked function (in this case SearchFilter) accepts whatever arguments that the hook trigger (either [apply_filters()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) for filter hooks or [do_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) for action hooks) is passing to it and the best way to know what they are is to search the code for the hook tag (e.g searchFilter) and see what they are.
However as stated above since we you are hooking it to a filter hook it will have at least one argument.

> What will be that argument / what will be it's type?
>   How can I determine for which action/filter there is any argument?

Same as above you can see that in the hook trigger function or by creating a test dump which would be something like this?

```
function test_dump($a1=null,$a2=null,$a3=null,$a4=null,$a5=null){
    if ($a1 !== null){
        echo '<pre>first argument: <br/>';
        var_dump($a);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    if ($a2 !== null){
        echo '<pre>2nd argument: <br/>';
        var_dump($a);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    if ($a3 !== null){
        echo '<pre>3rd argument: <br/>';
        var_dump($a);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    if ($a4 !== null){
        echo '<pre>4th argument: <br/>';
        var_dump($a);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    if ($a5 !== null){
        echo '<pre>5th argument: <br/>';
        var_dump($a);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

> Should every action / filter return the passed parameter?

Action hooks doesn't expect a return value so no, but a filter hook should return a value almost every time.

Comment: This anwer is gold!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know of to get args is to look up the do_action call for the hook you're using in the code. [adambrown.info](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/) has a great section on this. [Here's](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/pre_get_posts?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/query.php) the one you'll need.

Comment: I am still confused. I am not able to understand how many parameters should be accepted by function, and what will be those arguments?

Comment: Does the documentation on [`do_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) and [`do_action_ref_array()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action_ref_array) help you at all? I'm not sure which part of the code you're not understanding.